# Вывести в div-ы порядковые номера при помощи цикла js

Tags: javascript, html, циклы, for

Есть на странице 10 (в дальнейшем будет больше) `div`-ов.

Нужно в каждый выводить по порядку числа начиная с единицы:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var i; 
  i=1;i<20;i++;  
  var divs = $('.number-of-type');
  for(i in divs){divs[i].innerHTML=i}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='number-of-type'></div>
<div class='number-of-type'></div>
<div class='number-of-type'></div>
<div class='number-of-type'></div>
<div class='number-of-type'></div>
<div class='number-of-type'></div>
<div class='number-of-type'></div>
<div class='number-of-type'></div>
<div class='number-of-type'></div>
<div class='number-of-type'></div>
```

Но почему-то выводит с 0, как исправить?

Comment: `divs[i].innerHTML=i+1`

Comment: @Yaant так выводит только цифру 3 и больше ничего

Comment: Что по вашему делает эта строка `i=1;i<20;i++;` ? сначала i сделаем 1, потом проверяем что оно меньше 20, но это условие бесполезно, оно возвращает истину просто в никуда. и потом делаем i++; в итоге этой строки i просто равно 2. далее в цикле вы выводите i, никак его не изменяя. изменять i надо все таки внутри самого цикла вывода, например делая `innerHTML=i++`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var div = $('div');
  for (i in div) {
    div[i].innerHTML = i * 1 + 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: У Вас тоже выводит цифры начиная с нуля, а нужно чтобы выводил числа начиная с единицы в первом div, второй div -2, третий div -3....

Comment: Спасибо Вам! Работает как надо.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Если вам пофиг на Internet Explorer или вы готовы использовать [полифилл](https://github.com/imagitama/nodelist-foreach-polyfill) для forEach, то можно вот так:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(function(div, i) {
  div.innerHTML = i + 1;
});
```

```html
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

И не выведет, т.к. переменная i, определенная как var,  и переменная-итератор i в цикле for - две разные переменные.

```
for (i=0; i< divs.length; i++) {
  divs[i].innerHTML = i;
}
```

Как-то так.